# Why don't I get a collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I have a cube tagged "player", which needs to jump at certain locations, represented by Empty GameObjects.

I want to make a point system and that why I put on some of the places other game objects tagged "Coin"

The cube has an animation which plays each time it moves to another point recognized by clicking with the mouse on it.
When I jump on the coin location I want the Coin object to get destroyed.

I use this function:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin") {
        Debug.Log ("Plm");
        stroy (col.gameObject);
    }
```

The problem is that when I'm jumping at the Coin location nothing happens.
I have box colliders on both objects and `OnTrigger` checked on both.

Comment: Do you have a rigidbody on your `player`?

Comment: Questions about collision detection problems have been asked a thousand times. Have you checked : The rigidbodies ? The colliders ? (one with `IsTrigger` checked) ? Do you use 2D colliders ? If so, use `OnTriggerEnter2D` instead. Have you checked the [collision matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) ? Are you sure the coin is tagged "Coin" (and not "coin" or "COIN") ? Have you put a simple `Debug.Log("Collision")` outside the condition ?

Answer (score 4):

**1) Make sure one gameobject has a rigidbody**

To have the `OnTriggerEnter` happen you need at least one of the two object to have a `RigidBody` attached to it.

**2) Static Trigger Collider**

An object that has a collider and `isTrigger` checked but no rigibBody is considered a `Static Trigger Collider` which are [From Unity Documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

> This is a GameObject that has a Collider but no Rigidbody. Static colliders are used for level geometry which always stays at the same place and never moves around. Incoming rigidbody objects will collide with the static collider but will not move it.

This type of collider interactions is perfect for your coins because they do not move and stay static.

**3) Rigidbody Trigger Collider**

The next type of collider interactions is a `Rigidbody Trigger Collider` which are :

> This is a GameObject with a Collider and a normal, non-kinematic Rigidbody attached. Rigidbody colliders are fully simulated by the physics engine and can react to collisions and forces applied from a script. They can collide with other objects (including static colliders)

This type of collider is what you need on your `player` and as it says in the Unity Documentation it will be able to collide with the `Static trigger collider`.

**Important observation:**

Having `IsTrigger` set to true on your player collider will cause your player to **not respond as a solid object**

> A collider configured as a Trigger (using the Is Trigger property) does not behave as a solid object and will simply allow other colliders to pass through.

which might not be the most optimal solution for you because most of the time you want your player to be able to collide with other things like the ground. So you can set the `isTrigger` to false and just have a rigidbody on you player and it will react to the coins if they're set as `Static Trigger Collider`.

---

If you want an easy way to know what can collide with what [Read the colliders documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) and take a look at this chart that shows it in a more simpler way.

[image]